# routes.rb slows down startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, rack

My Rails project got 1127 Routes generated in `config/routes.rb`
On production server it takes about 2.5 minutes to start the puma server or to enter the console.

I've used bumbler and other tools to benchmark the environment.
There is nothing left, which slows down the startup.

I figured out, that when I remove all routes in `config/routes.rb` the server is started and the console is loaded in 2 seconds.

Is the startup time normal for a project of this size? (comparing routes count) 
Does anyone have an idea if there are possibilities to improve this?

***// Extension: 2020-05-12***

The routes.rb contains the routes in some seperate files:

```rb
require_relative 'routes/admin.rb'
require_relative 'routes/api.rb'
require_relative 'routes/backend.rb'
require_relative 'routes/demo.rb'
require_relative 'routes/group.rb'
require_relative 'routes/system.rb'
require_relative 'routes/partner.rb'
require_relative 'routes/sysop.rb'
require_relative 'routes/frontend.rb'

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/', to: 'backend/business#index'
  get '/backend', to: 'backend/business#index'

  constraints SysopConstraint.new do
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sysop/sidekiq'
  end

  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'

  extend AdminRoutes
  extend ApiRoutes
  extend BackendRoutes
  extend DemoRoutes
  extend GroupRoutes
  extend PartnerRoutes
  extend SystemRoutes
  extend SysopRoutes
  extend FrontendRoutes
end
```

I just made a try to find out which file needs the longest time to load, by covering the extends with a Benchmark.

```rb
list = [AdminRoutes, ApiRoutes, BackendRoutes, DemoRoutes, GroupRoutes, PartnerRoutes, SystemRoutes, SysopRoutes, FrontendRoutes]
Benchmark.bm do |bench|
  list.each do |route|
    bench.report(route.name) { extend route }
  end
end
```

First the routes get executed really fast. 
Then no output for a minute, then the routes are getting executed again, but this time much slower.

Can someone explain me whats happening in the background when booting an application?

```sh
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.4.2 application starting in production
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
              user     system      total        real
AdminRoutes     0.170508   0.000253   0.170761 (  0.170888)
ApiRoutes       0.776109   0.000345   0.776454 (  0.777914)
BackendRoutes   0.753472   0.011739   0.765211 (  0.766692)
DemoRoutes      0.005872   0.000158   0.006030 (  0.006032)
GroupRoutes     0.136586   0.000373   0.136959 (  0.136977)
PartnerRoutes   0.060478   0.000000   0.060478 (  0.060480)
SystemRoutes    0.005102   0.000000   0.005102 (  0.005111)
SysopRoutes     0.018995   0.000000   0.018995 (  0.018997)
FrontendRoutes  0.004853   0.000000   0.004853 (  0.004856)
              user     system      total        real
AdminRoutes    10.353290   0.000000  10.353290 ( 10.380565)
ApiRoutes      39.384480   1.441894  40.826374 ( 41.155395)
BackendRoutes  54.539170   0.343206  54.882376 ( 55.264573)
DemoRoutes      0.592922   0.008005   0.600927 (  0.601244)
GroupRoutes     8.710383   0.060063   8.770446 (  8.782207)
PartnerRoutes   4.623054   0.015728   4.638782 (  4.677382)
SystemRoutes    0.397222   0.004065   0.401287 (  0.401317)
SysopRoutes     1.646245   0.007859   1.654104 (  1.654451)
FrontendRoutes  0.627315   0.020184   0.647499 (  0.650795)
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.3 (ruby 2.6.6-p146), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 2, max threads: 2
* Environment: production
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
```

Comment: We have 1,269 routes and it does not take nearly that long. We have our routes split into several named route files (admin_routes.rb, sync_routes.rb, etc.). Then our routes.rb just references each route file with `draw :admin_routes` and the rest. We have 11 separate route files. We didn't do this for speed but for organization.

Comment: We also splitted our routes file into 9 separate files. Also for a better organization. I tested to remove the split and put all together, but this has no impact. @Dan

Comment: I didn't think it could help but I thought it was worth a mention. I'll keep thinking and asking around at my shop.